# Stability of a closed loop transfer function

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

Given the closed loop transfer function $W(s)$, I have to analyze the stability of the system.

$$ W(s) = \frac{\dfrac{2s + 2 + k}{s^2 + 3s +2}}{1 + \dfrac{2s^2 + 2s + ks}{s^3 + 3s^2 + 2s}} $$

After some calculations, I got

$$
W(s) = \frac{s(s+1)(s+2)(2s + 2 + k)}{s(s+1)(s+2)(s^2 + 5s + 4 + k)}
$$

Now, I should apply the Routh-Hurwitz criterion in order to analyze the stability of the system. However, I am having an hard time understanding whether I should simplify $s(s+1)(s+2)$ or not. If I am not mistaken, given that $s = -1$ and $s = -2$ are two poles which belong to the LHP, I should be able to simplify $(s+1)(s+2)$, while I don't know what to do with the pole in the origin.

I have tried to apply the criterion without simplifying anything and considering the polynomial $$Q(s,k) = s(s+1)(s+2)(s^2 + 5s + 4 + k)$$ Doing so, I get that the system should be marginally stable for $k > -4$. At the same time, however, I have tried to simulate the model and the response resembles that of an asymptotically stable system: does this imply that I am forced to simplify the pole/zero in the origin?

Comment: If I remember correctly, Jan Willems was not a great fan of zero-pole cancellation.

Comment: Since the coefficients are so nice, you can have perfect cancellation.  In a real-world system, it may be very different.

Comment: How did you arrive at this closed loop transfer function? Namely, if you just want to simplify $L(s)/(1+L(s))$ with $L(s)$ the openloop transfer function then certain pole-zero cancellation is allowed.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen The first expression of the closed loop transfer function has been given to me and I have to establish which $k$ makes the system asymptotically stable, marginally stable and unstable; I haven't derived the first expression by myself.

Comment: If you have a pole and zero at the same location then that pole won't be visible in the output of the system when simulating that system (and the initial condition of that pole is set to zero). But when that initial condition isn't zero, some other (disturbance) input might excite that pole or one uses some other way of measuring the output of the system then it might still be possible that such pole can become visible in the output of the system. But I do wonder why they provided you with the transfer function, namely even the transfer function in the denominator of $W(s)$ isn't minimal.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen If a pole is "excited" and then that excitation is "annihilated" by a zero, then somewhere in the system, there may be a signal growing quickly for a while.  The LTI system may be a linearization, meaning that the state may leave the region where the linearization is "good enough".  Also, there may be saturation.  If a signal is saturated, one won't have a "clean" excitation to cancel, but an extremely distorted version of it.  I haven't touched systems theory in over a decade. Am I writing nonsense?

Comment: Interesting. $W(s) = \frac{L(s)}{1+\frac ss L(s)}$

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to say that the system is marginally stable when $k > -4$, because the system is marginally stable when $k = -4$.

To do a proper stability analysis, we begin with the feedforward transfer function that is given by
$$
G(s) = \frac{2 s + 2 + k}{s^2 + 3 s + 2}
$$
If the open-loop transfer function $G(s) H(s) = G(s)$, then the closed-loop transfer function is given by
$$
G_{cl}(s) = \frac{G(s)}{1 + G(s)} = \frac{2 s + 2 + k}{s^2 + 5 s + 4 + k}
$$
The Routh–Hurwitz Stability Criterion can be applied. According to the criterion for a 2nd-order characteristic equation $s^2 + c s + 1 = 0$, the system is stable if $c > 0$ (you can actually prove this using the quadratic formula). Before applying the criterion, the characteristic equation should be normalized first so that we can make the apple-to-apple comparison:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 s^2 + 5 s + 4 + k &= 0 \\
 \omega_{n}^{2} &= 4 + k \\
 \frac{s^2}{\omega_{n}^{2}} + \frac{5}{\omega_{n}} \frac{s}{\omega_{n}} + \frac{\omega_{n}^{2}}{\omega_{n}^{2}} &= 0 \\
 \bar{s}^2 + \frac{5}{\sqrt{4 + k}} \bar{s} + 1 &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
From the normalized form of the characteristic equation, we can solve the inequality for $k$, and conclude that the closed-loop system will be stable when
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{5}{\sqrt{4 + k}} &> 0 \\
k &> -4 \\
\end{aligned}
$$
**Note:** It is actually unnecessary to use this normalization approach to apply the Routh–Hurwitz Stability Criterion for a 2nd-order system, if you understand the properties of the Quadratic equation, $a x^2 + b x + c = 0$.

However, it can be much more efficient when dealing when higher-order systems. Else, you need to be meticulous when creating the Routh–Hurwitz Table using the ordinary approach.